# Is there a way to do a transactional query/lookup for different types of documents with a common partitionKey stored in the same container

Tags: c#, azure, transactions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a CosmosDB container in Azure and it contains documents of three types (typeA, typeB, and typeC). There is only one typeA for every key, and multiple documents of typeB and typeC for each key (ex. typeA is a user profile with an id (which acts as the paritionKey), and typeB is an order made by that user, and typeC is a review written by that user -- typeB and typeC both use the user id as their partitionKey). How do I write a transactional operation to read all documents for a given user id? I'm hoping to do a point lookup of typeA, and a ReadManyAsync for typeB and typeC in a transactional manner.

**Example data:**

object of typeA

{

```
userId: 01234
lastPurchase: 01-02-2023
```

}

object of typeB

{

```
userId: 01234
purchaseId: 56789
purchaseQuantity: 1
```

}

object of typeC

{

```
userId: 01234
lastReviewWritten: 01-02-2023
reviewId: 101112
```

}

**This is what I've tried:**

`container.Database.BeginTransactionAsync()`

issue - Database does not have the BeginTransactionAsync() property

`container.CreateTransactionalBatch(new PartitionKey("/beneficiary")) .ReadItem(beneficiary).ExecuteAsync()`

issue - as far as i can tell this is only for one type of document at a time. If the type is not an issue for the read, do I just deserialize into typeA, typeB, and typeC in this function (by adding a 'type' property to each data type)?

Comment: Please edit to provide some sample data, along with what you've tried. FYI you can only execute transactional batch within a single partition (so all documents within a transactional batch need to have the same value for their partition key property); it has nothing to do with document "type" since that's not really a thing with Cosmos DB, as there are no types of documents, aside from what you construct in your app tier.

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon updated the question with a mock data model. If i've interpreted your answer correctly, than the `container.CreateTransactionalBatch(new PartitionKey("/beneficiary")) .ReadItem(beneficiary).ExecuteAsync()` should work and retreive all documents for that partitionKey? Is there a way to do the deserialization without having to add a `type` property to each data type? Something equivalent to the way `ReadManyAsync<typeB>` would query?

Comment: `CreateTransactionalBatch()` is a method on containers, not on databases (hence your first error). Also, you are misunderstanding the PartitionKey parameter - you need to specify the *value* of the partition key, not the *path* (the path is permanently set for the collection, at creation time). I don't understand what you mean by "one document at a time." I  suggest reading the docs on Transactional Batch. Once again: there is no "type" property.

Comment: The first error comes from trying to use `BeginTransactionAsync()` not `CreateTransactionalBatch()` -- do you know about the use case of one over the other?

Comment: Ah - right - I misread what you wrote (and correct - you're trying to use a transaction style that doesn't exist in Cosmos DB) . In any case, see my other comments.

Comment: I was looking at the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.createtransactionalbatch?view=azure-dotnet
and  `container.CreateTransactionalBatch(new PartitionKey("/path")) .ReadItem("01234").ExecuteAsync()` seems correct, no?

Any suggestions for deserializing the several document types that get returned when this call succeeds for all userId=01234?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read multiple documents at the same time, the easiest way is to use a query. In your case, `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.userId = '01234'`.

Because you are dealing with multiple entities, you will need to define the query and result set as a dynamic datatype, then inspect whatever property you are using to determine the entity, and deserialize into its appropriate object.

You see an example of this in this function here, [QueryCustomerAndSalesOrdersByCustomerId()](https://github.com/AzureCosmosDB/CosmicWorks/blob/master/modeling-demos/Program.cs#L367) from the [Cosmic Works Sample on GitHub](https://github.com/AzureCosmosDB/CosmicWorks).

In fact this example is nearly identical to your scenario in that the data is queried from a container that contains one customer profile document and all of that customer's sales orders. The container is partitioned by customerId.

Comment: Thank you for the example @MarkBrown -- is there no way to do this without a contract change to include a `type` property for the deserialization?
And is the Query the only way to handle multiple entity types? (there's no way to use a more efficient get call, like `ReadManyAsync`?)

Comment: Something like `ReadManyItemsStreamAsync` looks like a type-agnostic read for multiple documents via a stream (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.readmanyitemsstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet) -- do you have any suggestions on it's use and performance over performing a query? I see the comparison to a strongly typed call like ReadItemAsync is negligible (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/693)

Comment: On your deserialization question. How would you know what type to deserialize as unless you interrogated the raw JSON to figure out what type that was returned? You could use a base class initially to inspect the values but performance-wise it makes little difference.

Comment: ReadManyItemsAsync() requires you to know both the partition key and the id values for each document. I don't know what your id values are here as your example is incomplete but if you know both pk and id values for each document then this would be an option. ReadItemAsync is always going to be more performant than a query as queries must go through query engine whereas ReadItemAsync is a direct read from the backend store.